# countdown timer not working properly for seconds

Tags: javascript

I am creating a countdown timer for bidding auction, for single product it is working but when I make it dynamic for all products it is showing the timer but seconds are not changing, though the timer is working properly, but timer is not running in frontend as you can see in this link http://proffice.in/bidapp/ please help me with the javascript error. The error showing I  console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null on this line document.getElementById("cntdwn_"+show_id).innerHTML = DisplayStr; 
>           on countdown.js

```
    <?php 
        while($pro_data = $db->jas_fetch_array($products)){ 

             $closedate = date_format(date_create($pro_data['selling_end_date']), 'm/d/Y H:i:s');?>

                                        <script>
                                        TargetDate = "<?php echo $closedate ?>";
                                        ForeColor = "#04BFBF";
                                        show_id="<?=$pro_data["id"]?>";
                                        CountActive = true;
                                        CountStepper = -1;
                                        LeadingZero = true;
                                        DisplayFormat = "%%D%%d:%%H%%H:%%M%%M:%%S%%S";
                                        FinishMessage = "Bidding closed!";
                                        </script>
                                        <script language="JavaScript" src="<?=$wwwroot;?>assets/js/countdown.js"></script>
                                        <?php } ?>

    // here is my coutdown.js file    

    function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
      s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
      if (LeadingZero && s.length < 2)
        s = "0" + s;
      return "<b>" + s + "</b>";
    }

    function CountBack(secs,show_id) {
      if (secs < 0) {
        document.getElementById("cntdwn_"+show_id).innerHTML = FinishMessage;
        return;
      }
      DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, calcage(secs,86400,100000));
      DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, calcage(secs,3600,24));
      DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, calcage(secs,60,60));
      DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, calcage(secs,1,60));

      document.getElementById("cntdwn_"+show_id).innerHTML = DisplayStr;
      if (CountActive)
        setTimeout("CountBack(" + (secs+CountStepper) + ")", SetTimeOutPeriod);
    }

    function putspan(backcolor, forecolor,show_id) {
     document.write("<span id='cntdwn_"+show_id+"' style='background-color:" + backcolor + 
                    "; color:" + forecolor + "'></span>");
    }

    if (typeof(BackColor)=="undefined")
      BackColor = "white";
    if (typeof(ForeColor)=="undefined")
      ForeColor= "black";
    if (typeof(show_id)=="undefined")
      show_id = "";
    if (typeof(TargetDate)=="undefined")
      TargetDate = "21/06/2017 5:00 AM";
    if (typeof(DisplayFormat)=="undefined")
      DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
    if (typeof(CountActive)=="undefined")
      CountActive = true;
    if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined")
      FinishMessage = "";
    if (typeof(CountStepper)!="number")
      CountStepper = -1;
    if (typeof(LeadingZero)=="undefined")
      LeadingZero = true;


    CountStepper = Math.ceil(CountStepper);
    if (CountStepper == 0)
      CountActive = false;
    var SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 990;
    putspan(BackColor, ForeColor,show_id);
    var dthen = new Date(TargetDate);
    var dnow = new Date();
    if(CountStepper>0)
      ddiff = new Date(dnow-dthen);
    else
      ddiff = new Date(dthen-dnow);
    gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
    CountBack(gsecs,show_id);


//  console is showing error in this line

    document.getElementById("cntdwn_"+show_id).innerHTML = DisplayStr;
      if (CountActive)
        setTimeout("CountBack(" + (secs+CountStepper) + ")", SetTimeOutPeriod);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is that you are just creating your script using the loop. But not creating the Div where you need to show the counter, which is of course, your counter.

Please check whether any div with id "cntdwn_" with your corresponding show_id exists or not. In your url, I was not able to find on the page. Hope it helps. Let me know if it doesn't. :)